# nginx location redirect too many redirects

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I am trying to redirect all URLS from my site /search to /search/grid

using:

```
    location /search {
            return 301 /search/grid;
    }
```

this works to redirect /search but then /search/grid gives the HTTP error too many redirects, how can I only redirect if the path is only /search?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use either and exact match `location` block, or a `rewrite`:

```
location = /search {
    return 301 /search/grid;
}
```

Or:

```
rewrite ^/search$ /search/grid permanent;
```

See [this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) and [this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for more.

Comment: that works apart from if the path in the URL is /search/ then it doesn't redirect. How can it work for both /search and /search/ ? Thanks

Comment: The `rewrite` uses a regular expression, so using `^/search/?$` includes an optional trailing `/`. You could use a regular expression `location`, or add another exact match location block.